# Removing some items in Recyclerview using databinding shows empty space

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am using Firebase as my backend. I am using recyclerview to show a list of users. I've achieved that but now I now want to display only some users based on their "category" in the JSON. When I display the list without the gridview it works fine when I try to display the list in gridview I am seeing empty spaces in place of the users I've removed.

Below is code. My GridRecylerview

```
  mFragmentChatsBinding.rvChats.setHasFixedSize(true);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);

    mFragmentChatsBinding.rvChats.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

My JSON Response

```
    {"xxxxx@gmail,com":{
    "category":"admin",
    "email":"xxxx@gmail,com",
    "hasLoggedInWithPassword":false,
    "name":"xxxx"},
     "yyyy@gmail,com":{
    "category":"user",
    "email":"yyyy@gmail,com",
    "hasLoggedInWithPassword":false,
    "name":"yyy",}}
```

My Recyclerview Code

```
 private void initializeFirebase() {
    final Query refUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference(ConstantsFirebase.FIREBASE_LOCATION_USERS);
    refUsers.keepSynced(true);
        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, ChatsItemHolder>(User.class, R.layout.adapter_item_chats,
                ChatsItemHolder.class, refUsers) {
            @Override
            public ChatsItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                adapterItemChatsBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater
                        .from(parent.getContext()), viewType, parent, false);
                //adapterItemChatsBinding.tvUserName.setTypeface(Typefaces.get(getActivity(), Constants.FONT_ROBOT_REGULAR));

                return new ChatsItemHolder(adapterItemChatsBinding);
            }    
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ChatsItemHolder viewHolder, User user, int position) {

                        if (user.getCategory().equals("admin")) {                             
                            viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);                             viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.lnItemRow.removeAllViews();                               viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.lnItemRow.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);     
                        } else {
                            viewHolder.bindUser(user, ChatsFragment.this);    
                        }    
             mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();               
}
```

I am using the following code to not show the users I want

```
 if (user.getCategory().equals("admin")) {    
                            viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
                            viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.lnItemRow.removeAllViews();                               viewHolder.mAdapterItemChatsBinding.lnItemRow.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);      
                        } else {
                            viewHolder.bindUser(user, ChatsFragment.this);    
                        }
```

Is there any better way to remove some items in the recyclerview. If yes, What is it? If no, why am I getting empty spaces when I am using gridrecyclerview and working fine when I show a normal recyclerview?

Comment: You can achieve this by set filter on adapter.

Comment: I am using the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Comment: Then i think you can make query as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of removing the view remove the item from the list and set

> adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Can you tell me how to remove the item from the list ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to refresh you gridView or your adaptor.

For example

```
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
 grid.invalidateViews();
 grid.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I am unable to find invalidateViews method in recyclerview

Comment: you should invalidate your gridView

Comment: I've added my gridrecyclerview code in the question. Can you take a look and tell me how to invalidate